# Woocommerce checkout field label

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout

I know this is not posed as a standard layout.
But I need to enable the label for the checkout `field billing_address_2`
I've set the label value perfectly

```
$billing_new_order['billing_address_2']['label'] = __('Complex Unit Number', 'woocommerce');
```

But I need it to actually show in the form.
I cannot find a option in php to make sure the label is shown.

Could someone please give me some quick guidance to make sure the label gets shown?

Or is this strictly a css thing that I will need to queue a script just for this label. - which I feel is a bit overkill and bloating ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the php solution for anyone that wishes to have this issue resolved ..

If the Label does not show then clear the standard css classes that are associated to the field which might be resident.

```
$billing_new_order['billing_address_2']['label_class'] = '';
```

This made the label show up and conforms to the styling of the rest of the form.